# Why does outerHeight() returns function instead of actual height?

Tags: jquery

I'm having a function that centers a div.
It uses outerHeight() to determine div's height.
On one of my sites it works ok:

[image: outer height works fine]

But on the other site it returns a function:

[image: outherheight works none]

Why does it happen? How do I make it work on both sites?

Thank you!

Comment: How you can get the `(window)`'s outerHeight is completely beyond me. outerHeight doesn't work on document or window objects; you can read the documentation and see it plain as day. [This method is not applicable to window and document objects; for these, use .height() instead.](http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/)

Comment: @Ohgodwhy He's not using `outerHeight` on `window`, he's using it on `this` and `jQuery(this)`. We can't tell what `this` refers to.

Answer (score 0):

are you using the same version of jQuery (and/or jQuery UI) on both sites. It could be related to this bug: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12237